# Calling constructors of extended classes in a function

Tags: function, polymorphism

I have the following classes :-

```
Public abstract class A {
}

Public class B extends A {
    int a;
    B() {
        a=1;
    }
}

Public class C extends A {
    int a;
    C() {
        a=2;
    }
}
```

In a function :-

```
if(given == 1) {
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        B b = new B();
        listB.add(b);
    }
    return listB;
}
else {
    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        C c = new C();
        listC.add(c);
    }
    return listC;
}
```

As you can see I am doing the same thing over again.Is there any way to write a function for this to avoid repetitive coding using some polymorphism? 
The classes shown here are simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a factory method:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
   list.add(A.createInstance(given));
}
return list;

// in class A
static A createInstance(int given){
   switch(given){
      case 1: return new B();
      case 2: return new C();
   }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't give me "+given);
}
```